# Jboss 4.2.3 fails to deploy Java 8 compiled MBean

Tags: java, deployment, jboss, java-8, mbeans

I am migrating a legacy code to java 8 and after changing the Spring version to 3.2.10.RELEASE and deploying it on jboss 4.2.3 I am getting:

```
2014-09-02 05:57:57,396 ERROR [org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer] Could not create deployment: file:/project/SA/opt/jboss-4.2.3.GA/server/sa/deploy/sa/sa-pmt-service-1.0.4-SNAPSHOT-dev.sar
org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentException: MBean attribute 'name' must be given.
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceConfigurator.parseObjectName(ServiceConfigurator.java:783)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceConfigurator.internalInstall(ServiceConfigurator.java:449)
```

It was running fine on jdk 7 compiled version. Here is jboss-service.xml

```
<server>
  <loader-repository>
    com.sa:loader=pmt-password-service.sar
    <loader-repository-config>java2ParentDelegation=true
    </loader-repository-config>
  </loader-repository>

  <mbean code="com.ems.services.common.ServiceInvoker" name="jmx.service.ems:name=SAS_PMTPasswordService,version=1.0"
    xmbean-dd="resource:META-INF/serviceinvoker-xmbean.xml">
    <attribute name="Service">SAS_PMTPasswordService</attribute>
  </mbean>

    <mbean code="com.sa.services.pmtsender.PmtMomService"
        xmbean-dd="resource:META-INF/serviceinvoker-xmbean.xml">
        <attribute name="Listener">pmtMessageListener</attribute>
        <attribute name="MomServiceName">pmt-service</attribute>
        <attribute name="active">true</attribute>
    </mbean>
</server>
```

Comment: You know JBoss 4.2.3 is massively old and not designed or tested for the versions of Java you're throwing at it, right?

Comment: Yes, unfortunatelly I have to end this migration in two weeks and I don't think I can migrate the full Jboss to higher version.