# Migration JBoss EAP 4.2 from java 1.5 to java 1.8?

Tags: jboss, java-8, migration

right now my app use 4.2 jboss with java 1.5.

I manage to build my app (EJB, jsf, hibernate, seam) with java 1.8, but i get some problems with running jboss 4.2 with java 1.8.

So I wonder, whether it is even possible or it will be better to switch to another version of jboss(with will be also complicate)?

Thank you for clarification.

So another question appear, if I use new jboss and java8 , Am I need to change hibernate (eg. I use hibernate-ejb 3.3.2ga), jsf, etc. to newer version? Application was build with java 8 with success.

Comment: I doubt it... See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25625304/jboss-4-2-3-fails-to-deploy-java-8-compiled-mbean and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28496816/is-jdk8-a-supported-platform-for-jboss-6-as - time to migrate to wildfly...

Comment: You can't. Take @assylias's advice.

Comment: Check the [JBoss Windup migration tool](https://github.com/windup/windup/wiki).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't run JBoss EAP 4.2 on Java 1.8 (Or any other java newer than 1.6)

Use new version of JBoss EAP instead. This will give you better performance some cool new features and server will be easier to monitor and maintain.

Here is the [link](http://www.jboss.org/products/eap/download/)

Comment: your link is for EAP - the open source version has been renamed [wildfly](http://wildfly.org/)

Comment: EAP is available for dev purposes too.